# AVPlayer.status doesn't run when wrapped in a DispatchWorkItem with a Delay

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, avplayer, avplayeritem

Because I'm playing videos in cells I have an AVPlayer that plays videos in certain circumstances immediately and others it runs a few seconds later. When it runs immediately the `.status` works fine. But when I wrap it in a `DispatchWorkItem` with a `.asyncAfter` delay that same exact `.status` is never called. I also tried to use a `perform(_:, with:, afterDelay:)` and a `Timer` but this didn't work either.

```
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation? = nil
var workItem: DispatchWorkItem? = nil
var startImmediately = false
var timer: Timer?

viewDidLoad() {
    // add asset to playerItem, add playerItem to player ... 
}

func someCircumstance() {

    if startImmediately {

        setNSKeyValueObserver() // this works fine and .status is called

    } else {

        createWorkItem()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.33, execute: executeWorkItem) // this delay runs but .status is never called

        // perform(#selector(executeWorkItem), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.33) // same issue

        // timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.33, target: self, selector: #selector(executeWorkItem), userInfo: nil, repeats: false) // same issue
        // RunLoop.current.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }
}

func createWorkItem() {

    workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.setNSKeyValueObserver()
        }
    }
}

@objc func executeWorkItem() {

    guard let workItem = workItem else { return }

    workItem.perform()
}

func setNSKeyValueObserver() {

    // without a long explanation this sometimes has to start with a delay because of scrolling reason I also might have to cancel it
    observer = player?.observe(\.status, options: [.new, .old]) { [weak self] (player, change) in
                
        switch (player.status) {
        case .readyToPlay:
            print("Media Ready to Play")
                    
        case .failed, .unknown:
            print("Media Failed to Play")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown Error")
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use the older KVO API .status observer instead but the same issue occurred when using a delay

```
private var keepUpContext = 0

viewDidLoad() {

    // add asset to playerItem, add playerItem to player ...
    player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: [.old, .new], context: &keepUpContext)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if context == &keepUpContext {

        if let player = player, let item = player.currentItem, item.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp {
            print("Media Ready to Play")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be the delay.

**Update**

I just tried the following code and and this doesn't work either:

```
if startImmediately {

    setNSKeyValueObserver()

} else {

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.15) { [weak self] in
        self?.setNSKeyValueObserver()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding your observer after the player has loaded the content. It likely loads between the `viewDidLoad` and the delay. If you add `.initial` to the list of options when adding the observer, you'll be sure to get the state notification even if the player is already ready.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the `forKeyPath` parameter value to `#keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status)`

Comment: I tried that too but same issue. Thanks though

Comment: Have you checked the weak ‘self’ in DispatchQueue, it might be nil somehow. Also; You execute the work item in main queue which is also executing a block in the main queue.

Comment: I tried the work item on a background thread but same issue: `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.15, execute: workItem!)` I run some afterwards and I checked to see if the `observer` is nil and it always has a value. I just tried something else with a regular .asyncAfter and it works fine. Of course I can't cancel a regular .asyncAfter. But either way i would still like to know what the problem is

Comment: I see, even though you make it work to stop a work item that is already started you should test for isCancelled flag

`workItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
 guard (item?.isCancelled ?? true) == false else { return }
    self?.setNSKeyValueObserver()
}`

Comment: ok thanks for the help! I have to get ready to go to my daughter's graduation. I'll let you know the results once I try it. :)

Comment: Sure, Congratulations! :)

Comment: I actually said "thanks" with a cheers for the congrats earlier today twice but someone must've deleted it both times. So I'll say it again, Thanks for the Congrats :). I just got back and tried your code above but **self?.setNSKeyValueObserver()** always gets hit. This is what I tried `workItem = DispatchWorkItem { DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in guard let weakSelf = self else { print("self is nil") return } guard (weakSelf.workItem?.isCancelled ?? true) == false else { print("workItem is nil") return } self?.setNSKeyValueObserver()}}` The observer always get hit

Comment: No problem :) I just checked your initial code again. So you check status to determine if the item is ready to play right? In Apple's documentation, it states that: `The player’s status does not indicate its readiness to play a specific player item. You should instead use the status property of AVPlayerItem to make that determination.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1388096-status

Maybe you should observe status on `playerItem` ?

Comment: I tried observing the playerItem too. I didn’t include it but that also doesn’t work. I might have to use a TSI for this. This is a very strange problem. I edited the code in my question a bit to show everything that I tried. I also tried a `DispatchSourceTimer`, `DelayedOperationBlock`, `OperationQueue\OperationBlock`, and a couple of other custom delay/cancel methods that I found on google. Nothing works when using a delay. Also, I made a mistake yesterday, `.dispatchAfter` doesn’t work either. I didn't realize that I had setNSKeyValueObserver() set before calling  `.dispatchAfter`.

Comment: I’m on a slack channel with some very experienced developers. I asked over there and a guy said I need to check for `.initial` in addition to `[.new, .old]`. That actually solved the problem! I asked him to answer so that I can accept it and give him the credit. **THANK YOU** for your help!!!